# Is it possible to disable zoom using both keys as well as mousewheel in a page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, zooming, jquery-events, keydown

I want to disable zoom, be it <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>-</kbd>/<kbd>+</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + Scroll Wheel in all browsers. I tried using the code given in [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/946284/disabling-page-zoom-in-ie7-jquery-js/946455#946455). I also tried to disable the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key by using the following code:

```
$(document).keydown(function(e){
    if(e.keyCode == 17)
        return false;
    });
```

But it doesn't work. I actually don't want to alert the user that zoom is disabled, so I can't use the `alert()` inside the above code.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Even you disable the Ctrl + -/+ keys & and Ctrl + scrollwheel, I can still go to View->Zoom in my browser and change it there. Your best option is to build your design so that it's not reliant on a specific text size. Also, some people have a hard time reading small text.. that's why there's a zoom feature.

Comment: Try using fixed font size in pixels e.g. `body * { font-size: 12px; }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Zoom is there for a reason. Understand it, build around it, but don't try to disable it. In the end, it's a bowser feature that is out of your hands. You can hack and slash but I doubt you'll ever find a perfect or even stable solution for what you are asking.

Comment: The problem is that I've built on a page which uses overflow:hidden to prevent scrolling. If the person zooms out, he'll see the region which I had hid. This makes the whole thing look ugly.